# How can I properly check if a string needs to be encoded for a valid NSURL?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I'm making a web browser and I'd like to add a simple URL correction function.

The user types or pastes text in a UITextField.

```
NSString *text = textField.text;
```

I'm trying to fix the URL by passing through two stages:

**(1)** Check if the string needs to be encoded.

```
BOOL encode = NO;

// Check if the string needs to be encoded.

if (encode) {

    text = [text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
}
```

**(2)** Check if the URL has a scheme.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:text];

if (!URL.scheme) {

    URL = [URL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", text]];
}
```

Example:

If the user copy & pastes this URL:

> [http://www.efevresi.gr/τέλος-για-το-μεγαλύτερο-λεωφορείο/](http://www.efevresi.gr/%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CF%84%CE%BF-%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%89%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BF/)

The URL should be encoded to:

> http://www.efevresi.gr/%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CF%84%CE%BF-%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%89%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BF/

But if the user copy & pastes the encoded URL:

> http://www.efevresi.gr/%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CF%84%CE%BF-%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%89%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BF/

It *shouldn't* re-encode it.

Any suggestions? It there a proper function for this already? Can you point me towards something I can add into my project?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445003/check-nsstring-is-encoded-or-not

Comment: If the user copy and pastes an already encoded string I won't be able to know the original string.